# using different threads to do processing in web application

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a Java EE web application. Now when a particular request comes (say /xyz url patter) I want to do complex procesing as follows

Each of the following 3 steps are very complex and takes time.

1. Get data from one table from DB.Table has huge data and querying takes time.
2. Make a web service call to some other  webserive A and get its data.
3. Make another web service call to some otheer webserice B and get its data .
4. Do some processing by using output of 1, 2, 3

1, 2, and 3 are independent of each other so can be called in parallel.

Now the questions are:

1. Can I do operations 1, 2, and 3 in three separate threads?
2. Is it advisable to create 3 threads for each request?
3. Should I use thread pooling?

Comment: The easy way is use Ajax

Comment: @Gray its 100 % now :).I had forgotten to accept it previously

Comment: @nidhin : This is not related to ajax.I need to give some output o for some input i .To compute o i need to do step 1,2,3 , 4  as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your **first question** I go through the 4 steps:

1. Yes, if the database driver you are using allows concurrent access, respectively is safe to use from different threads.
2. A web service is normally designed to deal with different requests at the same time so this should work as well, the question here is how many threads you want to use (and how long it takes to process one request) and whether the web service will guard itself against too many requests at once.
3. The same applies here.
4. Yes, but you have to do synchronization here, as in: wait until all threads have received their results. You can realize this with a [java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

**Second question**
That depends on your data and especially how fast the web services will answer, you should try it out.

**Third question** Definitively, that's what they are for. This will also help you to structure your application.

Answer (score 1):

1) Can i do operations 1 ,2 and 3 in three separate threads?
Yes, you can.

2) Is it advisable to create 3 threads for each request?
As long as these things don't depend on each other, and as long as you're not depending on getting these in the same transaction, then it seems like it should be ok. You will have to handle the case where one or more threads don't succeed, of course. You'll need a separate watchdog thread to cancel the threads if they take too long or if one comes back with a failure.

3) Should I use thread pooling? 
Regardless of what else you do, whenever you use threads you should use a pool. That way if there's a problem where threads don't complete or go into some bad state or otherwise become unavailable, you protect your application from running out of threads.